# Overlapping divs with the same font have different letter spacings

Tags: html, css

I have an overlaying div with exact the same offsets as the underlaying.
Same to the font properties.

So mostly the upper div (with transparent background) is exactly overlaying the font of the other.

Normally the upper font is transparent as well and is just there for selecting and writing the text.

Now I thought my script is buggy, because after inserting text, the indent was not the same anymore.

After some testing I came across this mysterious bug:

When there is a space followed by a capital A or Y, or a capital A, L, P or Y followed by a space, the underlaying text appears a little bit more left for every case mentioned before.

Is this a known bug?
Is it even a bug?
And how to deal with this issue?

Thank ya in advance.

[image: Picture of the buggy text]

Comment: try letter-spacing for both layers to be the same

Comment: Can you add the source code that problem reproduce?

Comment: @ZiadDarwich letter-spacing does not solve this issue.

Comment: @sanriot I can post some related code snippets later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, I solved the problem myself.
This seems to occur when one div is contenteditable and the other is not.
Making both editable is fixing it.